# How to Configure Hazelcast Clusters in local environment to test

Tags: hazelcast

I'm working on creating Hazelcast backup cluster along with the primary cluster. 
It's like I want to setup primary cluster in one machine and backup cluster in another machine to have the backup maps.
How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to synchronize an entire cluster from a remote cluster, you'll need Hazelcast's WAN Replication feature which is available in Enterprise version.  Please see in documentation at https://hazelcast.com/product-features/wan-replication.

If you actually only want to maintain backups within the same cluster by virtue of having multiple nodes within the same datacenter then this is available out of the box in open source.  For example, Map by default has backup count of 1 so if you have 2 machines clustered, you will already have a backup of every entry.